# How can I keep from generating inappropriate words when autogenerating strings from an alphabet?

Tags: dictionary, filtering

Is there a downloadable dictionary (essentially just a textfile) that contains common swear or otherwise inappropriate words in different languages?

Background: I'm rewriting an URL Shortener (Just a Proof of Concept app - the world has enough shorteners already anyway) and for that I convert Numeric IDs into Strings by Base36 encoding them. Now the problem with that approach is that it's sequential, so the unlucky people who shorten the URL that comes after faf or fucj may not be happy with their results, unless they are precisely waiting for that moment and use it to shorten the URL of their favorite Politician.

So I want a blacklist. InsultMonger doesn't really help here.

*How appropriate. You fight like a cow.*

Comment: I changed your question to avoid the case of someone thinking you wanted a list of inappropriate words to use based on just the title.  Feel free to flip back if you think I've overstepped.

Comment: Nah, that's fine. I wasn't really sure how to formulate the title anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just remove all the vowels (and Y) from your potential alphabet, then anyone who sees a swear word must have an overactive imagination.

Comment: That's actually an interesting approach, especially because removing the Y as well is cruicial as it can double an a U.

Comment: like the people who see the fsck shirts?

Comment: For my purposes, that's what I went with, but the list below can also be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a large multilingual list: http://nerdcereal.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2007/04/multilingualswearlist.txt